# The unsubscribe () in Rxjs method does not work on React js

Tags: reactjs, rxjs

In the file timer.js I am exporting this variable  initTimer (create stream)

```
   export const initTimer=new Observable((observer)=>{
    interval(1000)
    .subscribe(val=>{
      observer.next(val)})
    })
```

in App

```
  const [sec, setSec] = useState(0);
  const [status, setStatus] = useState("start" | "stop" | "wait");
 
  const subscribe=()=>{
     return initTimer.subscribe({next(x){
      setSec(x=>x+1000)
  }})}
  useEffect(() => {
    if(status==="start"){
      subscribe()
    }
    if(status==="stop"){
    subscribe().unsubscribe()
    }
  
  }, [status]);
 
  const start = React.useCallback(() => {
    setStatus("start");
  }, []);
 
  const stop = React.useCallback(() => {
    setStatus("stop");
    setSec(0);
    
  }, []);
 
 
 
  return (
    <div>
      <span> {new Date(sec).toISOString().slice(11, 19)}</span>
      <button className="start-button" onClick={start}>
        Start
      </button>
      <button className="stop-button" onClick={stop}>
        Stop
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When "start" is triggered, I subscribe to the timer, call the method
"next" and add the resulting result to state. But when the "stop" condition is triggered, I must unsubscribe and the timer must stop counting, but when I unsubscribe the timer is reset and the countdown begins. How do I stop the timer?

Comment: You need to unsubscribe from the original object, but you create a new one instead, it re-sets the timer, then you unsubscribe from it, then the first one carries on ticking.

Comment: `.subscribe().unsubscribe()` - that doesn't look right. Shouldn't it be `subscribtion =  initTimer.subscribe()... subscribtion.unsubscribe()`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to store your subscription so that you can use it to unsubscribe later.

You can do this using `userRef`:

```
const [sec, setSec] = useState(0);
const [status, setStatus] = useState("wait");
const sub = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
  // Subscribe and store subscription
  if (status === "start") {
    sub.current = initTimer.subscribe({
      next(x) {
        setSec(x => x + 1000);
      }
    });
  }

  // Unsubscribe
  if (status === "stop") {
    if (sub.current) {
      sub.current.unsubscribe();
    }
  }

  // Return cleanup function to unsubscribe when component unmounts
  return () => {
    if (sub.current) {
      sub.current.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
}, [status]);

const start = React.useCallback(() => {
  setStatus("start");
}, []);

const stop = React.useCallback(() => {
  setStatus("stop");
  setSec(0);
}, []);
```